# Convert Rust vector of tuples to a C compatible structure

Tags: python, rust, ctypes

Following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312885/pass-python-list-to-embedded-rust-function?lq=1) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182843/pass-a-c-array-to-a-rust-function), I've currently defined a Rust 1.0 function as follows, in order to be callable from Python using `ctypes`:

```rust
use std::vec;

extern crate libc;
use libc::{c_int, c_float, size_t};
use std::slice;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn convert_vec(input_lon: *const c_float, 
                          lon_size: size_t, 
                          input_lat: *const c_float, 
                          lat_size: size_t) -> Vec<(i32, i32)> {
    let input_lon = unsafe {
        slice::from_raw_parts(input_lon, lon_size as usize)
    };
    let input_lat = unsafe {
        slice::from_raw_parts(input_lat, lat_size as usize)
    };

    let combined: Vec<(i32, i32)> = input_lon
        .iter()
        .zip(input_lat.iter())
        .map(|each| convert(*each.0, *each.1))
        .collect();
    return combined
}
```

And I'm setting up the Python part like so:

```python
from ctypes import *

class Int32_2(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("array", c_int32 * 2)]

rust_bng_vec = lib.convert_vec_py
rust_bng_vec.argtypes = [POINTER(c_float), c_size_t, 
                         POINTER(c_float), c_size_t]
rust_bng_vec.restype = POINTER(Int32_2)
```

This seems to be OK, but I'm:

- Not sure how to transform `combined` (a `Vec<(i32, i32)>`) to a C-compatible structure, so it can be returned to my Python script.
- Not sure whether I should be returning a reference (`return &combined`?) and how I would have to annotate the function with the appropriate lifetime specifier if I did

Comment: Do not put solutions in your question. If you want to share the code that worked for you, you can post an answer of your own.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The most important thing to note is that there is **no such thing** as a tuple in C. C is the *lingua franca* of library interoperability, and you will be required to restrict yourself to abilities of this language. It doesn't matter if you are talking between Rust and another high-level language; you have to speak C.

There may not be tuples in C, but there are `struct`s. A two-element tuple is just a struct with two members!

Let's start with the C code that we would write:

```C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
  uint32_t a;
  uint32_t b;
} tuple_t;

typedef struct {
  void *data;
  size_t len;
} array_t;

extern array_t convert_vec(array_t lat, array_t lon);

int main() {
  uint32_t lats[3] = {0, 1, 2};
  uint32_t lons[3] = {9, 8, 7};

  array_t lat = { .data = lats, .len = 3 };
  array_t lon = { .data = lons, .len = 3 };

  array_t fixed = convert_vec(lat, lon);
  tuple_t *real = fixed.data;

  for (int i = 0; i < fixed.len; i++) {
    printf("%d, %d\n", real[i].a, real[i].b);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

We've defined two `struct`s — one to represent our tuple, and another to represent an array, as we will be passing those back and forth a bit.

We will follow this up by defining the *exact same* structs in Rust and define them to have the *exact same* members (types, ordering, names). Importantly, we use `#[repr(C)]` to let the Rust compiler know to not do anything funky with reordering the data.

```rust
extern crate libc;

use std::slice;
use std::mem;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct Tuple {
    a: libc::uint32_t,
    b: libc::uint32_t,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct Array {
    data: *const libc::c_void,
    len: libc::size_t,
}

impl Array {
    unsafe fn as_u32_slice(&self) -> &[u32] {
        assert!(!self.data.is_null());
        slice::from_raw_parts(self.data as *const u32, self.len as usize)
    }

    fn from_vec<T>(mut vec: Vec<T>) -> Array {
        // Important to make length and capacity match
        // A better solution is to track both length and capacity
        vec.shrink_to_fit();

        let array = Array { data: vec.as_ptr() as *const libc::c_void, len: vec.len() as libc::size_t };

        // Whee! Leak the memory, and now the raw pointer (and
        // eventually C) is the owner.
        mem::forget(vec);

        array
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn convert_vec(lon: Array, lat: Array) -> Array {
    let lon = unsafe { lon.as_u32_slice() };
    let lat = unsafe { lat.as_u32_slice() };

    let vec =
        lat.iter().zip(lon.iter())
        .map(|(&lat, &lon)| Tuple { a: lat, b: lon })
        .collect();

    Array::from_vec(vec)
}
```

We must *never* accept or return non-`repr(C)` types across the FFI boundary, so we pass across our `Array`. Note that there's a good amount of `unsafe` code, as we have to convert an unknown pointer to data (`c_void`) to a specific type. That's the price of being generic in C world.

Let's turn our eye to Python now. Basically, we just have to mimic what the C code did:

```python
import ctypes

class FFITuple(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", ctypes.c_uint32),
                ("b", ctypes.c_uint32)]

class FFIArray(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("data", ctypes.c_void_p),
                ("len", ctypes.c_size_t)]

    # Allow implicit conversions from a sequence of 32-bit unsigned
    # integers.
    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, seq):
        return cls(seq)

    # Wrap sequence of values. You can specify another type besides a
    # 32-bit unsigned integer.
    def __init__(self, seq, data_type = ctypes.c_uint32):
        array_type = data_type * len(seq)
        raw_seq = array_type(*seq)
        self.data = ctypes.cast(raw_seq, ctypes.c_void_p)
        self.len = len(seq)

# A conversion function that cleans up the result value to make it
# nicer to consume.
def void_array_to_tuple_list(array, _func, _args):
    tuple_array = ctypes.cast(array.data, ctypes.POINTER(FFITuple))
    return [tuple_array[i] for i in range(0, array.len)]

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./target/debug/libtupleffi.dylib")

lib.convert_vec.argtypes = (FFIArray, FFIArray)
lib.convert_vec.restype = FFIArray
lib.convert_vec.errcheck = void_array_to_tuple_list

for tupl in lib.convert_vec([1,2,3], [9,8,7]):
    print tupl.a, tupl.b
```

Forgive my rudimentary Python. <s>I'm sure an experienced Pythonista could make this look a lot prettier!</s> Thanks to @eryksun for [some nice advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984688/convert-rust-vector-of-tuples-to-a-c-compatible-structure/30992210#comment50015596_30992210) on how to make the consumer side of  calling the method **much** nicer.

## A word about ownership and memory leaks

In this example code, we've leaked the memory allocated by the `Vec`. Theoretically, the FFI code now owns the memory, but realistically, it can't do anything useful with it. To have a fully correct example, you'd need to add another method that would accept the pointer back from the callee, transform it back into a `Vec`, then allow Rust to drop the value. This is the only safe way, as Rust is almost guaranteed to use a different memory allocator than the one your FFI language is using.

> Not sure whether I should be returning a reference and how I would have to annotate the function with the appropriate lifetime specifier if I did

No, you don't want to (read: *can't*) return a reference. If you could, then the ownership of the item would end with the function call, and the reference would point to nothing. This is why we need to do the two-step dance with `mem::forget` and returning a raw pointer.

Comment: This is incredibly thorough. Thank you so much.

Comment: Here are the documentation links for [`from_param`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.from_param) and [`errcheck`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.errcheck).

Comment: @eryksun Any chance you could put together a basic example incorporating your suggestions?

Comment: @eryksun I've updated, thanks again! The part I'm least sure about is the `errcheck` function; does it make sense the way I wrote it?

Comment: I'd use `return ctypes.cast(array.data, ctypes.POINTER(FFITuple * array.len))[0]` to return a `FFITuple` array. Also, I forgot that in `from_param` you should pass along an instance of the class, e.g. `return arg if isinstance(arg, cls) else cls(arg)`.

Comment: @Shepmaster +1 Nice idea. Regarding your statement, *"To have a fully correct example, you'd need to add another method that would accept the pointer back from the callee, transform it back into a Vec, then allow Rust to drop the value"* - Is this doable in Rust? Can you return the *same* pointer from Python and allow Rust to catch the *same* and drop it?