# Passing an array from C to Rust via FFI with #[!no_std]

Tags: arrays, c, rust, ffi, rust-no-std

All the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29182843/477476) about passing an array from C to Rust use `std::slice::from_raw_parts` to convert the raw C pointer and some length information into a Rust. In an embedded context ([MOS 6502](https://llvm-mos.org/) in my case), there might not be a `std` library available. So **in a `#![no_std]` context**, what is the nicest way of passing an array from C to Rust for (potentially mutable) processing?

Comment: I added the [rust-no-std] tag to your question and needed to remove the [pointers] tag as the question would have exceeded the [five tags limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34732/288173) after my edit. If you feel that the [pointers] tag is more relevant to the question than [rust-no-std], feel free to revert (but note that I also fixed a typo – you probably don't want to revert that part of the edit either way).

Comment: @EliasHolzmann thanks, the [rust-no-std] tag is exactly what I should have used, I just didn't know about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While `std::slice::from_raw_parts` is not available in a `no_std` environment, [`core::slice::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html) *is* available, so you can simply use that.

In general, anything that is in `std` and not somehow platform dependent (so, not I/O, heap allocation and the like) should also be available in `no_std` environments through the `core` crate.

Comment: Additionally, since Rust 2018 you can also use `core` in non-`no_std` crates. `std::slice::from_raw_parts` is just an alias to `core::slice::from_raw_parts`, which can be used directly **all the time**.